# Variance of sum of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent exam scores. Each $X_i$ is a random variable with $\mu=75$ and $\sigma=25.$ Let $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i).$ Then what does Var$(S_n)$ equal? Is it just $25$? If so, why?

Comment: You teacher must have sophisticated sense of humor.

Comment: What, if any, is the difference between $\sigma$ and Var$(X_i)$?

Comment: I don't think there is one?

Comment: Rephrased the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606234/variance-of-sum-of-random-variables-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: +1 for a perfectly correct answer!  But I am surprised, not at your giving a correct answer (you are invariably correct), but rather at the completely different tenor from your typical answers that are so kindly written and so helpful even to the most hapless questioners.

Comment: +1 for a perfectly correct answer and a poker face with this joke.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Guilty. I was tempted into sin by the opportunity to give a doubly small answer. Any questions OP has about the reason can be dealt with in comments.

Comment: Ok so $S_n$ is just a number so it's variance is 0?

Comment: That's right, it is constant. You have supplied the reason that I left out in the quest for a minimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depend on the distribution of your score. (There can be a lot of different distributions with the same mean and variance).

If the score distribution is normal distribution, then the distribution of $S_n$ is $25^2 \chi^2_n$. Where $\chi^2_n$ is the [Chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with n degree of freedom. And the variance of $S_n$ is $2*25^2*n=1250n$

Comment: No, no! $S_n$ is a sum of numbers not $X_i$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Note that variance of random variable is not random quantity. It is some number which gives idea about distribution of random variable. And variance of any real number is zero.